# PAGE_COUNT not rendered correctly in JasperReports...?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have added the footer ***Page x of y*** to my report, but the PAGE_COUNT doesn't seem to work.

Maybe the problem occurs because I have many subreports?

I get:

```
Page 1 of 1

Page 2 of 0

Page 3 of 0

Page 4 of 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show "Page X of Y" using a single text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673263/show-page-x-of-y-using-a-single-text-field)

Answer (score 11):

Well, don't know elder versions but in JasperReports 4.5.1; you can define two text fields both includes `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` variables. The one which has `EvaluationTime: now` shows current page number; the other one with `EvaluationTime: report` shows the number of total pages. A simple trick but works :)

Answer (score 6):

Changing the `evaluationTime="Report"` solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Summary: To have the page number and the page number in a TextField.

Step 1: Create a variable that indicates the number of the current page.
     Settings:
* Name: CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER

- Variable class: Java.lang.Integer
- Calculation: nothing
- Reset Type: None
- Increment type: Page
- Variable Expression: $ V {CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER} == null? $ V {PAGE_NUMBER}: $ V {PAGE_NUMBER} +1

Step 2: TextField Settings

- Text Field Expression: "PAGE:" + $ V {CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER} + "/" + $ V {PAGE_NUMBER}
- Expression class: Java.lang.String
- Evaluation Time: Auto

And that's all. No need to add anything to it to give you a result like: Page 1/3 | Page 2/3 | Page 3/3.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

http://jasperforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2873&group_id=102&atid=612

But the book JasperReports for Java Developers (p 146) says that PAGE_COUNT is the total number of pages in the report. I guess the bug is in the book.

Comment: Actually, PAGE_COUNT is calculated like other variables, so you can get the state of it along the way. (a feature, not a bug :-)

Answer (score 2):

our reports look like :

http://pastebin.com/m401fa41

1st part, interpreted during page generation, gives the # of the current page (`evaluationTime="Now"`)

2nd part, interpreted at the end of the report , gives the total # of pages (`evaluationTime="Report"`)

HTH

Comment: Your sample further helped me place the two fields to forma seamless legend. Nice trick, aligning the first one to the right and the second one to the left. I wish things were more "floatable" in JR.

Answer (score 2):

Actually It Is a BUG! And confirmed by developers.

See link:
[jasper community bug tracker link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/3788)

PAGE_COUNT is not correctly calculated, when using property on BAND: "Split Prevent"

Answer (score 2):

The solution is the follow :
We must not put $ { V PAGE_NUMBER }+ "/" + $ { V } PAGE_NUMBER in the same field.

the proper way is to put $ { V PAGE_NUMBER } in separated field and "/ " + $ { V } PAGE_NUMBER in the other field

it work for me

sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

I haven't access to the jaspercommunity (to check the link shared), but I do a good workaround :D

Use 4 texts, like this:

```
txtStatic1(Page) txtField1($V{PAGE_NUMBER})  txtStatic2(of) txtField2($V{PAGE_NUMBER})
```

Where:

```
txtField1($V{PAGE_NUMBER}) -> AVAILABLE TIME = PAGE
txtField2($V{PAGE_NUMBER}) -> AVAILABLE TIME = REPORT
```

It's works to me.