# Jasper Reports Show "Page X of Y" using a single text field

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to create one text field that contains `Page X of Y`, without splitting it in two parts, as per the common solution. My textfield contains `"Page " + $V{currentPage} + " of " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}"` with `evaluationTime=auto`.

Let's say I have a report with 10 pages. Three are the **Title Band**, six are **Detail Band** and one is the **Summary Band**. My results show `"Page 0 of 10"` for the **Title Band**s, correct counts for the **Detail Band**s, then `"Page 0 of 10"` for the **Summary Band**s.

How do you ensure the variable is calculated everywhere, not only on **Detail Band**?

Comment: `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` contains the current page number, what you want is `$V{NumberOfPages}` so you can use it in one text box with `EvaluationTime: Now`. Otherwise you need the two text box solution like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424468/page-count-not-rendered-correctly-in-jasperreports)

Comment: @KCD does your JasperReport has a ${NumberOfPages} variable? I don't seem to be able to see it here.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Jaspersoft Studio, 6+

For Jaspersoft Studio v6, or if the first page number is duplicated, try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42550057/59087), which uses `$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}` and `$V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGE}` with an evaluation time of `Master`.

## Jaspersoft Studio

For other versions of Jaspersoft Studio, try the steps outlined in the subsequent subsections.

### Create Variable

Create a variable as follows:

1. Create a variable called `V_CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER`
2. Select the variable to open its properties (illustrated below)
3. Set **Expression** to: `1`
4. Set **Initial Value Expression** to: `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}`

- If the page number shows `0`, use `$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + 1`.
- If the page number always shows `1 of Y`, set **Expression** to `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` instead of the initial value expression, and leave the initial value expression empty.

1. Set **Reset type** to: `Page`

These settings are illustrated in the following figure:

[image: Current Page Number Variable]

Setting the **Expression** to `1` prevents its value from being `null`. That is, if the footer shows *Page **null** of 4* it probably means that the **Expression** hasn't been set.

The variable is created.

### Add Page Footer

Add a **Page Footer** band as follows:

1. Select the report in the outline panel
2. Check **Summary With Page Header And Footer** to ensure the page footer appears on the summary page.
3. Add a **Page Footer** band.

The footer is added.

### Create Text Field

Create a text field as follows:

1. Drag and drop a *single text field* onto the **Page Footer** band.
2. Select the text field.
3. Set **Expression** to: `msg("Page {0} of {1}", $V{V_CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER}, $V{PAGE_NUMBER})`
4. Set **Evalutation Time** to: `Auto`

These settings are illustrated in the following figure:

[image: Single Text Field]

The single text field is created.

### Preview Report

For a report with three pages plus a summary page, previewing the report shows:

[image: Page 1]

The summary page shows:

[image: Page 4]

Answer (score 30):

I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37552266/59087), but ended up with incorrect page numbers: {1/7, **1/7**, 2/7, 3/7, 4/7, 5/7, 6/7}.

For JasperReports 6+, use `MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE` and `MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES` system variables and remember to set the text field evaluation time to `Master`:

```xml
<textField evaluationTime="Master">
    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[msg("Page {0} of {1}", $V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}, $V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES})]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

See: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/book/index.html

Comment: This is the best way for doing this, at least, for me. I'm using Jaspersoft Studio latest version.

Answer (score 11):

The common approach, as you mentioned, uses two separated text fields:

**Current page number**

`$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` with EvaluationTime: Now

**Total page number**

`$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` with EvaluationTime: Report

Answer (score 6):

For page history show like:  **Page: 1 of 5**

Make the text field value to be like below and change the evaluation time to `Master`:

```
"Page: "+$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}+" of "+$V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES}
```

Source:

```
            <textField evaluationTime="Master">
                <reportElement x="224" y="0" width="186" height="15" uuid="6641bb8b-9f48-4832-942b-8b04220030e6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page: "+$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}+" of "+$V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

Comment: I tried all the solutions described here, but this one it was the only which works and also the is the simplest one. Jasper 6.6.0 here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the current page number, `evaluationTime=now` and `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` is your answer.

Unfortunately I don't think you can achieve what you want because there is a bug in [PAGE_COUNT](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/3788) when Split Allowed is on for the Detail band. Otherwise `evaluationTime=now` and `"Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " of " + $V{PAGE_COUNT}"` would probably work.

Answer (score 2):

This work for my (little different of Dave's Answer)

*Using JasperSoft Studio

[image: Capture: adding Variable]

Then put a Text field with the expression:

```
"Pág. " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} +"/" + $V{V_CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

This should help, by using   *evaluationTime* as **Report**

```
   <textField>
        <reportElement x="497" y="0" width="32" height="12" forecolor="#7E8083"
                           uuid="ef663cfd-4058-40bb-a6d9-de7f9a8164be"/> --update your elements here
        <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
            <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7" pdfFontName="OpenSans-Regular.ttf"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
            <![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " of"]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField evaluationTime="Report">
        <reportElement x="529" y="0" width="7" height="12" forecolor="#7E8083"
                           uuid="ef663cfd-4058-40bb-a6d9-de7f9a8164be"/>  --update your elements here
        <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
            <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7" pdfFontName="OpenSans-Regular.ttf"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression>
                <![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see page no like `Page 1 of 5` on right side of the report footer use ireport or jasper report Palette Tools(Page X of Y) is perfect.

**If you want to see page no like `Page 1 of 5` on left side of the report footer use ireport.**

Please follow below steps

1. Create function variable as like

[image]

2. Please take a TextField

   "Page "+$V{V_CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER}+" of "+ $V{PAGE_NUMBER}

[image]