# How to display page x of y in my jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am generating the reports using jasperreport-4.5.0.It is generating the report properly.But if i have huge data in my database then the report vl display in different pages.So my requirement is if my report has 12 pages then i want to display page 1 of 12,page 2 of 12,page 3 of 12....like this in my page header band.How can i do this can any one give an idea regarding this.

Comment: You can read [JR faq](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish//jasperreportswebsite/JR%20Website/jasperreports_faq.html#Page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show "Page X of Y" using a single text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673263/show-page-x-of-y-using-a-single-text-field)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the evaluationTime="Report" attribute to achieve this.

Consider the following example, we first print "PAGE" then we print the page number using the default evalutaionTime attribute. This will print the current page number, then we print OF and finally the page number with evaluation time set to "report" which will print the total number of pages.

```
        <band height="20">
        <elementGroup>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="709" y="0" width="53" height="20"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["PAGE"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>

            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="762" y="0" width="23" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>

            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="785" y="0" width="29" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["OF"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>

            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="814" y="0" width="26" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>

        </elementGroup>
    </band>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for giving the reply.After posting the question here i just read a sample and tried like this.Can i use like this suggest me.I have taken a static text there i mentioned Page, and then window-->pallete-->Page Number,one more static text bof for Of,then again window-->pallette-->Total Pages.

Comment: Hi,I dont want to display the page number if at all if my report has only one page.How can i achieve this.

Comment: Will this dynamically size the textbox containing your pages numbers?