# Jasper Reports: center current page number and total page number

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to print the current page number and the total page number in the page footer of a Jasper Reports report as phrase like "page 2 of 10". The phrase must be centered between the page margins. The text pattern is locale dependent.

The natural approach would seen to use a message pattern to do the formatting and and translation, e.g. msg($R{msg_page_number}, $V{PAGE_NUMBER}, $V{TOTAL_PAGE_NUMBERS}). This is not possible because there is no variable like TOTAL_PAGE_NUMBERS. One has to evaluate the PAGE_NUMBER variable at different times of the report layout. As a consequence one has to use multiple text elements to print the line. This makes centering very hard as none of the text element is actually at the center of the page.

Is there a way to print the current page number and the total page numbers in a phrase like "$R{page} X $R{of} Y" horizontally centered on the page?

Comment: The approach given by http://stackoverflow.com/a/37552266/1410078 works here also!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show "Page X of Y" using a single text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673263/show-page-x-of-y-using-a-single-text-field)

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
<textField evaluationTime="Master">
    <reportElement x="4" y="9" width="546" height="22" uuid="b2d67140-3666-4968-8b46-89672b6fb6d5"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE} + " of " + $V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: It's important to notice that the evaluation time is set as `Master` otherwise the variables will produce nulls.

Comment: Does the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There is a variable for this purpose, and you are already using it. In fact, the same variable by which you are using to display the current page number (i.e:  $V{PAGE_NUMBER} ), can be used to show the total page count. The only difference is that you should change the evaluation time for that. The default is set to '**NOW**' (so the first PAGE_NUMBER variable it's ok), while on the second one you should set it to '**REPORT**'. You should end with a textField component looking like this:

```
<textField evaluationTime="Report">
        <reportElement uuid="b3d3c256-49ad-492b-8f6e-37ac3a3f2d61" style="Column header" x="678" y="0" width="40" height="13" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
            <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The result would be:
[image]

Comment: I know that. But that requires two text fields and leaves open my core requirement: centering the combined text of those text fields.

Comment: I don't know any possible way to do that with just a single component (i.e a single expression) up until i've followed Jasper. Using two of them doesn't cost anything. Are you using any tool for the generation of the report (i.e: of the jrxml)? If so, it's all about placing the components on the required spot (center) of your footer. If you don't you can just use the components 'horizontalAlignment' property. Since there are two ui components, the first should get a value of 'Right', and the second should get 'Left' (while they are placed beside to each-other).

Comment: It will not work. Since both text element have a different width (e.g "page X" for the current page and "Y" for the total pages) the visual center of the combined text "page X of Y" cannot be determined from the text elements involved. Also the text "page" is not of fixed but is locale specific, i.e. it might considerably longer or shorter than "page".

Comment: @Endrik: It is possible to use a single field. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37552266/59087

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to solve your issue.

take two fields 
Field1 shall be `$V{Page_Number}`  set evaluation time property . now
Field2 shall be `$V{Page_Number}`  set evaluation time property .  report

Your problem is solved....