# how to display page x of y in jasper report 5.5.1 in "single textfield" its giving alignment issue?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a situation  where i need page number in footer in this format:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
page 1 of 4212                                              printed date:
```

page no should be left align to left margin. i used this expression

```
"Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+ " of "+ $V{PAGE_NUMBER}
```

but it always give output

```
"Page 1 of 1"
```

how to achieve it in single text field which is left aligned???
please help me to sort out this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show "Page X of Y" using a single text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673263/show-page-x-of-y-using-a-single-text-field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/893771/printing-page-x-y-single-textfield-logic-jasper-ultimate-guide-section-1922

Create a variable with this definition (note the resetType)

```
<variable name="currentPageNumber" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Page">
<variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Page number Field (note the evaluation Time):

```
<textField evaluationTime="Auto">
<reportElement uuid="847e339f-a1a6-492d-868b-b233f71785b4" x="166" y="22" width="100" height="20"/>
<textElement/>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{currentPageNumber} + " of " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```